# Blazor - textarea bound to oninput, but not being called when the value of text area changed with javascript

Tags: blazor

I have a textarea bound as below

```
<textarea id="markdownEntry" class="w-100 h-100" bind="@MarkdownContent"
                      @bind-value="MarkdownContent"
                      @bind-value:event="oninput"                       
                      placeholder="Enter markdown here..."></textarea>
```

but I would like the oninput to fire when the value of the text area is updated with javascript as well (needed to create a editor)
I tried the following js but doesnt seem to work

```
function forceUpdate(input) {

    var event = new Event('input');
    input.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

I also tried changing `input` to `change`

Comment: have you tried the ```onchange``` event instead of the ```oninput``` event?

Comment: @SreeramNair that fixed the problem above, but broke the other thing i had `oninput` for was that i needed oninput update on each keystroke, where is onchange is only fired onblur and such

Comment: Why not add both the events and try

Comment: fixed it with changing how the event in js is created, answer below

Answer (score 3):

```
function forceUpdate(input) {

    var event = new Event('input', {
        'bubbles': true,
        'cancelable': true
    });
    input.dispatchEvent(event);

}
```

Fixed the issue